# Alternating or concurrent yet sync'd directory walking in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, os.walk, xlsxwriter

I'm not sure this question is realistic or indeed possible, but here goes.  I have two directories lets call them FIRST_DIR and SECOND_DIR, and in each folder I have matching logs and log names like below..

```
FIRST DIR
  F_log1.txt
  F_log2.txt
  ...

SECOND_DIR
  S_log1.txt
  S_log2.txt
  ...
```

I have seen examples on SO like that shown below from previous posts, but this processes all logs in one directory first and then all logs in the second directory.  I'm more looking for processing F_log1.txt then S_log1.txt and F_log2.txt then S_log2.txt, so that I can gather like for like log stats to plot into an Excel chart using xlsxwriter as I go.

```
paths = ('C:\FIRST_DIR', 'C:\SECOND_DIR')
for path, dirs, files in chain.from_iterable(os.walk(path) for path in paths):
```

The above would normally be fine for a couple of logs, I could collect lists of stats from each log and name the lists accordingly based on log number and then refer to them at the end of processing, but these logs are 100MB in size and often 50+ in number with up to 20,000 stats collected per log, so perhaps too many stats to store in memory.

Is there anyway around this problem?

Thanks for reading,
MikG

Comment: You basically want to do the merge step of a merge-sort over two generators from the different directories...